# Managed Identity w/Azure Functions and Storage accounts

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-managed-identity

What is the appropriate way to use managed identity with Azure Functions and Storage accounts if the the AzureWebJobsStorage app setting is required by the function host? Is there a managed identity version of the storage account connection string that doesn't include the access key?

Comment: as far as I know, there's no other way to define it rather then by using the connection string in the settings.json. I've sent and email to a MSFT employee and hopefully there will be another way for it.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible to configure a function app to authenticate with its storage account via managed identity.

Full details are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial#use-managed-identity-for-azurewebjobsstorage)

In summary, in the app settings for the function app:

- delete setting for "AzureWebJobsStorage"
- create a new app setting named "AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName"
- the value of the new setting should be the name of the storage account

Ensure the function app has "Storage Blob Data Owner" role over the storage account. If the function app uses the storage account's queue (e.g. queue binding) then it will also need "Storage Queue Data Contributor" role.

Answer (score 2):

While you can't use Managed Identity to authenticate to the storage account directly, you can store the access key in Key Vault and fetch it from there using [Key Vault References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references) using Managed Identity.

Just wanted to share this because I believe its great to use KeyVault References instead of directly using access keys in the app settings.

Comment: While this does work as a "better than nothing" solution, it does still cause issues concerning Key rotation on the storage account itself.  If you were to rotate your key, you'd have to update the Key Vault, and then your function would have to get the updated key (which on consumption plan might happen with the next run, but not necessarily on app service plan hosted functions).  Just something to think about. It would be much better if the Function could use the Managed Identity directly for this look up (and all other storage-account bindings) at some point in the future.

Comment: Agreed. While not exactly the same request, this [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/34917490-don-t-hardcode-the-storage-account-connection-st), I believe should address this. Please feel free to up vote this for it to gain more traction.